# Get accelerometer values in time

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors

I have to get the accelerometer values in time.
I saw the `Sensor` class and the `SensorEventListener` but this listener notify only when the value changes and I need a periodic notification (also if the value do not change).
Otherwise I would like to continuously read the accelerometer value but it is not possible according to this thread: [Get current SensorEvent value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29052204/get-current-sensorevent-value)

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to continuously "read" the sensor values even when they are the same as before? If you need to calculate some output on a regular basis, then a better solution might be to set up a timer that triggers on the required intervals at which time you use the values from a set of variables that are updated whenever the sensor values change. That way even if they don't change, the timer will initiate the calculations.

Kaamel