# How to collect data from multiple mobile sensors at once in Java?

Tags: java, android-sensors, sensormanager

I want to collect data from the accelerometer, gyroscope and magnetometer all at once. I am currently using the `SensorManager` service which is based on the `SensorEvent`. The problem with this is that I can only get the data from 1 sensor at a given point in time. So in time t1 I am getting data from accelerator, in t2 I am getting data from gyroscope and in t3 i am getting data from magnetometer.

My code is as follows:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
        sText.setText("S: " + event.sensor.getStringType());
    }
    else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE){
        sText.setText("S: " + event.sensor.getStringType());
    } 
    else if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD){
        sText.setText("S: " + event.sensor.getStringType());
    }
}
```

Instead of having to work with the three sensors at 3 different times, I want to be able to collect the data from all sensors in one time interval. Is this possible?

Comment: How do you expect that to work if they all share the same text field? 1 text field can't show 3 things at the same time

Comment: I dont want to just print the different sensor types. I want to use the collected data (at a certain time) to calculate positional and rotational offset from the previous  state of the device. The problem is that with the SensorEvent, i cannot gain access to each of the sensors in the same time interval, so my calculations are not correct since the collected data has a difference in time.

Comment: You seem to have made the assumption that these cannot occur concurrently based on no evidence at all. You have registered a callback. There is nothing to say that the same callback couldn't be called from multiple threads and be executed concurrently. You wouldn't notice with your current implementation because all of the threads are competing to set the same piece of text. Step 1) stop doing that

Comment: Well im a C++ developer, and i only moved to java because it was the easiest way of accessing the sensor data of mobile devices. Thats besides the point. Can i get the data of all sensors at once every 100 milliseconds? If i can set delta time as a constant of 100ms it would make my calculations and integrations considerably more accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little late, but may be useful for others - you can use simple workaround:

select sensors with highest update frequency and "synchronize" all other sensors data with them via global variables. E.g. (for accelerometer as main sensor):

```
...
float mAccX;
float mAccY;
float mAccZ;

float mGyroX;
float mGyroY;
float mGyroZ;

float mMagX;
float mMagY;
float mMagZ;

...

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
        sText.setText("S: " + event.sensor.getStringType());
        mAccX = event.values[0];
        mAccY = event.values[1];
        mAccZ = event.values[2]; 
        
        // use all sensors data here
        processAllSensorsData(mAccX, mAccY, mAccZ, 
                              mGyroX, mGyroY, mGyroZ,
                              mMagX, mMagY, mMagZ);
    }
    else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE){
        sText.setText("S: " + event.sensor.getStringType());
        mGyroX = event.values[0];
        mGyroY = event.values[1];
        mGyroZ = event.values[2]; 
    } 
    else if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD){
        sText.setText("S: " + event.sensor.getStringType());
        mMagX = event.values[0];
        mMagY = event.values[1];
        mMagZ = event.values[2];
    }
}
```

Or use some kind of interpolation (linear of quadratic), but in that case you get current sensors values with some delay.

And also use separate `SensorEventListener` for each sensor.

Answer (score 0):

When the sensors are changed you are going to get all the events related to each one of them. For each event, `onSensorChanged` is going to get called.

If you want to access all these events at a time, you should put them in some buffer.

One way to do that is as follow

```
// At class level
private Map<Integer, Stack<SensorEvent>> eventsBuffer = new HashMap<>();

// to be called from constructor
private void initEventsBuffer() { 
     eventsBuffer.put(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER, new Stack<>());
}

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
        eventsBuffer.get(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).push(event);
    }
    else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE){
        eventsBuffer.get(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE).push(event);
    } 
    else if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD){
        eventsBuffer.get(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD).push(event);
    }
   processEvents();
}

   private void processEvents() {
   // Start reading from the stack based on event type
       for (Map.Entry<Integer, Stack<SensorEvent>> entry : stack.entrySet()) {
            SensorEvent sensorEvent = entry.getValue().pop();
            Integer eventType = entry.getKey();
            // process now
        }
}
```

Comment: But still onSensorChanged is going to be called in different time for each sensor event (regardless of the sensor type). So if I am still not going to get the readings of the sensor data at one time. For example, how do i get the data of each sensor every 100 milliseconds?

Comment: Oh well, this is a push mechanism. i.e. event will be only triggered when there has been change. What you want is a pull mechanism. Not sure if its supported.

Comment: so i cant literally extract info from sensors at will? I have to wait for an update from the sensors?

Comment: I am afraid so. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29052204/get-current-sensorevent-value